# How to install with an easy way an ios app from a file (without apple store)

Tags: ios, xcode, installation

How to install easy an ios app from a file

I am creating an app for a company with 10 employees.
They all should install the app easy without technical know how and without deploying the app to apple-store ?
Also new employees should have a way to be able to install the app in seconds (minutes)

Is it possible to send an email to the employees with an attachement of the app, so they can install the app by doubleclicking.

In Androids world, it is easy. They just can run an .apk file.

What is the way in the apple's world ?

Comment: See: [Distribute Ipad App without app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885112/distribute-ipad-app-without-app-store), [Distribute App to multiple iPads without App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30922782/distribute-app-to-multiple-ipads-without-app-store), [How to distribute my finished app without app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33922189/how-to-distribute-my-finished-app-without-app-store)

Comment: What is wrong with this question ? Comment if you dare before downvote.

Comment: More that 100 SO hits for `[ios] distribute without app store is:question` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is offered by the [Apple Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/).
This allows you to develop and distribute in-house apps to your employees.
There is no way to distribute public "App Store" apps without the App store (excluding apps in beta testing through TestFlight).

Comment: Ok I see. Apples world is just special complicated. Android is set for this. Thanks.

Comment: There is definitely a difference between iOS and Android philosophy: Apple prefers security over simplicity (from a technical POV) while Android gives more simplicity while less secure (by less secure I mean that the processes around app publishing are less restrictive. Which leave more vulnerable spots than a locked down pipe like Apple's). IMO both approach have their pro and cons.